# oauth_access_token in facebook API

Tags: python, facebook, user-interface, token

I am trying to access my facebook profile using facebook api. My python code is the above:

```
import facebook

graph = facebook.GraphAPI("oauth_access_token")
profile = graph.get_object("me")
friends = graph.get_connections("me", "friends")
graph.put_object("me", "feed", message="I am writing on my wall!")
```

I ve create a facebook app, I am have app id and sexret. However I dont know how to access oauth_access_token. Any idea?

I found this [example](http://theamdara.blogspot.gr/2013/06/how-to-get-facebook-oauthaccesstoken.html)> However, I am received the following:

```
{
   "error": {
  "message": "Invalid redirect_uri: \u039f\u03b9 \u03c0\u03b1\u03c1\u03ac\u03bc\u03b5\u03c4\u03c1\u03bf\u03b9 \u03c4\u03b7\u03c2 \u03b5\u03c6\u03b1\u03c1\u03bc\u03bf\u03b3\u03ae\u03c2 \u03b4\u03b5\u03bd \u03b5\u03c0\u03b9\u03c4\u03c1\u03ad\u03c0\u03bf\u03c5\u03bd \u03c4\u03b7 \u03c3\u03c5\u03b3\u03ba\u03b5\u03ba\u03c1\u03b9\u03bc\u03ad\u03bd\u03b7 \u03b4\u03b9\u03b5\u03cd\u03b8\u03c5\u03bd\u03c3\u03b7 URL.",
  "type": "OAuthException",
  "code": 191
    }
}
```

Edit: I taking access token from [here](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/access_token/). It returns to me user and app token. So I use the following code to post in my facebook account:

```
import facebook
oauth_access_token = "****"
graph = facebook.GraphAPI(oauth_access_token)
me = "****"
profile = graph.get_object(me)
graph.put_object(me, "feed", message="I am writing on my wall!")
```

What have to put in acces_token and to me???

Answer (score 1):

There's an OAuth example here: https://github.com/pythonforfacebook/facebook-sdk/tree/master/examples/oauth

Comment: ImportError: No module named google.appengine.ext. What module do I have to install??

Answer (score 1):

You have two choices :
Either you'll go to [graph Api Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/) and manually get an access token(copy/paste it),under "get access token" button(easy but not permanent solution),
or,
you ll make a [manual login flow](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/v2.0).

In order to use OpenGraph you need to have a valid access token.That's what the response means.

Also,your call has to be like that:

```
profile = graph.get_object('me') (with quotes)
```

You can also check `[Pythonforfacebook][3]`

Answer (score 0):

You can go to facebook developers->tools menu, or to [link](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me?fields=id,name&version=v2.0) to get your access token. You have to choose your data and extension permissions in order to authenticate those actions. And get the access token.
Your code is

```
 import facebook
 import json
 token = 'your access token'
 graph = facebook.GraphAPI(token)
 profile = graph.get_object("me")
 graph.put_object("me", "feed", message="I am writing on my wall!")  `
```